# Why is python throwing error : AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, opencv3.0, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to run the following code, but python is throwing the error that numpy has no argument 'append' for the line that says: "ids.append(id)"

```
path = [os.path.join("data", f) for f in os.listdir("data")]
faces = []
ids = []

for image in path :
    img = Image.open(image).convert('L')
    nimg = np.array(img, 'uint8')
    id = int(os.path.split(image)[1].split(".")[1])
    faces.append(nimg)
    ids.append(id)
    ids = np.array(ids)
clf = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()
clf.train(faces, ids)
clf.write("classifier.yml")
```

Comment: `ids = np.array(ids)` should probably be outside the loop, if needed at all. Generally, re-assignment of a different type to the same variable should involve a double-take.

Comment: @user2864740. Thanks. it worked now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting ids into an array after the first iteration. When running it, you should have only one item in the array as is. I would move the line `ids = np.array(ids)` to outside the for loop. See below:

```py
path = [os.path.join("data", f) for f in os.listdir("data")]
faces = []
ids = []

for image in path :
    img = Image.open(image).convert('L')
    nimg = np.array(img, 'uint8')
    id = int(os.path.split(image)[1].split(".")[1])
    faces.append(nimg)
    ids.append(id)

ids = np.array(ids)
clf = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()
clf.train(faces, ids)
clf.write("classifier.yml")
```

If you wanted to truly have it be an array, you would have to use the following styled code, but a list should also be fine until the end.

```py
ids = np.array(ids)
ids = np.append(ids, [id])
```